# Lightweight laptop with non soldered RAM

Tags: laptop

I'm looking for laptop with following conditions:

- Weight: up to 1.4 kg
- Screen: up to 13.3″ or up to 14″ if FullView screen,
  at least Full HD resolution (1920х1080).
- RAM and SSD replacability (non soldered)
- Maximum perfomance
  for applications, not games (AMD Ryzen prefereable)
- Cost: around $1000

Most suitable laptops are Lenovo IdeaPad 720S-13ARR, Asus ZenBook, Acer SWIFT 5, Huawei MateBook 13 and Xiaomi Mi Notebook Air 12.5". But they all have soldered RAM, so I can't extend it if needed.

Are all ultrabook manufacturers making RAM on-chip ? Or is there any model with extensible SODIMM slot ? Maybe some OEM manufacturers do that, like Pegatron ?

Comment: I have never seen a consumer laptop with soldered RAM. Most laptops are built for RAM and SSD upgrades and whose laptop or part manufacturers often offer (albeit overpriced) upgrades on their sites for specific models.

Comment: @BennettYeo Unfortunately all models that I've mentioned are with soldered RAM. The most lightweight ultrabook with non-soldered RAM I've ever seen is HP ProBook 430 G5, but its weight is about 1.5 kg.

Answer (score 2):

The LG Gram 2018 (13.3 or 14 inches) should be what you are looking for.

The 2018 lineup has one soldered memory slot and one socketed memory slot which is replaceable.

For example the [**LG Gram 13Z980**](https://amzn.to/2ED6dxe) model.

This is the Crucial compatible upgrades page for it: https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/LG-Electronics/lg-gram-13z980